# Simple GCD Serial Queue example like FIFO using blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I read Apple documentation on how to Use serial queues to ensure that tasks to execute in a predictable order but now i am confused too much.
Some how i am able to work serially but still i am not clear so i need simple serial example for my methods to execute serially.

I divided my functionality  in to 4 parts and now want them to execute Serially

```
[self ReadAllImagesFromPhotosLibrary];

[self WriteFewImagestoDirectory];

[self GettingBackAllImagesFromFolder]; 

[self MoveToNextView];
```

Comment: If you are satisfied by one of the answers below, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 42):

To follow-up and improve *[iCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397915/icoder)*'s answer, you could and should do the following.

```
dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.unique.name.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
        [self ReadAllImagesFromPhotosLibrary];
    }); 
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
         [self WriteFewImagestoDirectory];
});
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    [self GettingBackAllImagesFromFolder]; 
});
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    [self MoveToNextView];
});
```

Despite the above calls being **async**, they will be **queued and run serially** as the **DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL** states. The difference between **sync** and **async** is that with **sync**, your *code will pause and wait* for the block answer before running the following code, thus potentially freezing your UI if the execution time is long. Whereas with **async**, the *code runs on and the block is returned **asynchronously***.

However, the tasks you have stored in the **DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL** will wait and be executed one after the other in the order they were added, thanks to GCD (Grand Central Dispatch).

Answer (score 5):

```
dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.unique.name.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
        [self ReadAllImagesFromPhotosLibrary];
             dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
                     [self WriteFewImagestoDirectory];
                     dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
                         [self GettingBackAllImagesFromFolder]; 
                         dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
                              [self MoveToNextView];
                         });
                   });
              });
    });
```

I think the above code should work, but make sure the UI operations are executed in the main thread. Hope it helps.

Comment: what? how about one dispatch async with 4 method calls? (does the same thing)

Comment: It makes no sense to recursive dispatch the calls. It is useless overhead.

Comment: the "com.unique.name.queue" could be anything right? Still why did you name it like that? what does **com** mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSOperationQueue` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to 1 (or even set dependency for each NSOperation, so it won't start before its dependency is finished).

Here is [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html) Class Reference.

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948804/nsoperationqueue-serial-fifo-queue) question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not much aware of existing API for doing the same with blocks, if any.

But the same can be done by defining blocks(representing the operations you want) in a fashion that they point to next block to proceed if any. Also, you can put the whole processing in a separate queue.

snippet for having blocks executing in serial fashion

```
BLOCK A(NEXT BLOCK reference){  
->Do the the required Task  
->If(next Block reference)  
--->Then call that block 
->Else  
--->Exit or have a callback on mainthread   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not try the GCD, it guarantees the sequence of operation and also has sync and async capabilities

Answer (score -2):

I had some success with a pattern like this in a similar hunt in Swift 3.0 ...

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "com.foo.bar")

serialQueue.sync {self.readAllImagesFromPhotosLibrary()}

serialQueue.sync {self.rriteFewImagestoDirectory()}

serialQueue.sync {self.gettingBackAllImagesFromFolder()}

serialQueue.sync {self.moveToNextView()}
```