# Handle Multiple Concurrent UIAlerts in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification, uialertcontroller

Is there a framework or method to handle multiple concurrent UILocalNotifications?

I have multiple concurrent UILocalNotifications that get turned into UIAlertControllers when the applications is active.  Is there some sort of way to buffer UIAlerts so they won't fire all at the same time. Perhaps some sort of pre-existing framework or method that would buffer these alerts.

Comment: There is no such framework. You need to write code to manage the alerts .Normally all the alerts are presented on a serial queue!!!

Comment: Is there a framework or example of a serial queue?

Comment: there are many examples out there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421450/simple-gcd-serial-queue-example-like-fifo-using-blocks .Also refer apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a framework for this. You need to write code for this and I would recommend presenting the alerts on a serial queue. Here is an example of a serial queue that you may be able to use a kind of templet:

```
dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.unique.name.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
        [self ReadAllImagesFromPhotosLibrary];
    }); 
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
         [self WriteFewImagestoDirectory];
});
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    [self GettingBackAllImagesFromFolder]; 
});
dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
    [self MoveToNextView];
});
```