# Swift OperationQueue for URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue

I am an Android developer currently learning Swift. Can you help me with the OperationQueue please?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

     var movieArray :[Movie] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let queue = OperationQueue()

        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

        for index in 1...5
        {
            queue.addOperation {
            self.process(value: index)
            }
        }

    }

    func process(value:Int)
    {
        print("Start for: \(value)")

        let url = NSURL(string: URL_API+"\(value)")

        //fetching the data from the url
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
            {

                if let resultArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "results") as? NSArray
                {
                    //Some Code...

                }

                print("Finish for: \(value)")
            }
        }).resume()

        print("End for: \(value)")
    }

}
```

What I expected to get is:

```
Start for: 1
Finish for: 1
End for: 1
Start for: 2
End for: 2
Finish for: 2
Start for: 3
Finish for: 3
End for: 3
Start for: 4
Finish for: 4
End for: 4
Start for: 5
Finish for: 5
End for: 5
```

What I got is:

```
Start for: 1
End for: 1
Start for: 2
End for: 2
Start for: 3
End for: 3
Start for: 4
End for: 4
Start for: 5
End for: 5
Finish for: 1
Finish for: 5
Finish for: 3
Finish for: 4
Finish for: 2
```

They not sequential, how can I make them so?

Comment: You need subclass the class Operation for your specific operation, and override the main function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the operations are added sequentially it's not guaranteed that they finish in the same order because 
`dataTask` works asynchronously.

The order `Start - Finish - End` will never happen anyway.
Due to the asynchronous behavior the order of one data task is always `Start - End – Finish`.

You need an asynchronous `Operation` described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561169/trying-to-understand-asynchronous-operation-subclass/48104095#48104095)

In the asynchronous `Operation` call `finish()` in the completion block of the data task.

---

Note:

Don't use `NS...` classes in Swift if there are native counterparts

- `NSURL` → `URL`
- `NSDictionary` → `[String:Any]`
- `NSArray` → `[[String:Any]]`

And don't `value(forKey` which has a special functionality. Use key subscription `dict["key"]` or `object(forKey`. And the `.allowFragments` read option is pointless in Swift if the expected type is a collection type. Omit the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on the **Managing Dependencies** section in below document for your solution:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation
or

refer this thread
[NSOperationQueue serial FIFO queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948804/nsoperationqueue-serial-fifo-queue)

either you have to make logic that when your first operation's finish/fail is called you should add the new operation to queue and reduce the task from the task stack.